# ATmega16 programing-registers mismatchs

Tags: c, usart, atmelstudio, atmega16

I am programming **ATmega16** and I chose that controller in device manager(**atmel studio 6.2**) but the registers don't match with the registers in the datasheet for ATmega16. I am using ICE 3 and I tried with the simulator but it is the same result. Register **UCSRC** is different, from some other controller and can't write in it, even though I set `MSB` to `one`.

Comment: Is your problem with UART communication of ATMEGA16 ? Please Elaborate your question. Put some code to understand what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2466.pdf) of ATMEGA16, it is not required to set **MSB** of **UCSRC** as its initial value is `1`. 
When you are working with UART you need to make sure that,

1. You are setting proper `UBRRL` and `UBRRH`, according to controller clock using formula as below:

   `FOSC/16/BAUD-1`
2. Enable `RXEN` and `TXEN` from `UCSRB`
3. Set the proper bits in `UCSRC`according to your requirement of `stop bit` and `parity bit`

Please refer following image :
   [image]

Comment: @Milos: You are welcome. If above answer worked for you then mark this answer as accepted, so that will be useful to others